# Is it righteous to give zakat or sadaqah from the income of a job which requires ongoing bribery to keep?

Tags: zakat, work, sadaqah

Suppose a person is doing a sophisticated job with no haram at all, but he has got that job through fraud like bribing.   He has to give bribe to some officers yearly in order to remain in the job.  But his job is not at all haram. And he is performing his job with integrity.  In order to supply bread and butter for his family members, he has to perform this bribing activity (no option for him).

With this background, he performs a charity of 4% of his income (not of saving but income) in order to rise in the eyes of Allah.

Will Allah consider this sadaquah and a righteous deed, as money is coming out of job which he has got through bribe.

Note:- He hasn't taken any bribe or performed any job which is haram.

Comment: I found some fatwa about people who got their job by bribing (once, not yearls) to get the job. Some scholars say that the prohibited bribery is the one who inverts a the rights of somebody so that they will lead to injustice.

Comment: @Medi1Saif but in this case .. Is his monthly income is haram? Can he pay zakat out of that money?

Comment: Do you want me to post an answer? Scholars say if the money he earns is from his job and because of his skills it's his halal income!

Answer (score 2):

Brother aoa
I have researched alot and I got to know that(sorry to say) your job is .........
I cannot say as I do not want to disheart you (forgive me)

According to an example 
A seed sown in the ground is haram as it was stolen and the farmer grows that tree with hardwork he looks after it day and night but the problem Is that when it gives fruit the farmer has nothing but that tree for earning but as the root or the start was haram so all is haram either you work day or night the tree in the first place was not your property

So comparing your story with this ,the job that you tell is not the persons, abviously the officers are not considering him good enough for the job but the man bribes (which is a big sin) and takes the right of some one

And another aspect is that food which you say bread and butter is the responsibility of Allah he does not need to bribe ,he needs to look for another job ,if there are difficulties Allah has promised in the Quran 
( After every hardship there is always ease)
So brother I hope you under stand

Allah knows the best
So worship him and ask Allah to give him a bribe free job

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good answer , But as you were mentioning "You" and "Your" everywhere in answer.. let me make very clear , I just mentioned a case.. I am not the person who is going through this condition :D